# Why did the Tardis turn red at the end of Turn Left?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

At the end of Turn Left, when the Doctor finds out about Bad Wolf, he runs back to the Tardis. The interior has turned completely red.

I know the out-of-universe reason is *mood lighting for the dramatic finale ups the ante*. But has there ever been a convincing in-universe explanation put out?

The start of the following episode, The Stolen Earth, has the Doctor and Donna running out of a red Tardis and then running back into a red Tardis moments later. But by the time of the next scene it's back to its usual yellowish colour scheme. So I'd guess that it was red for only 2-3 minutes, tops.

**What, if anything, explains the Tardis's sudden and transient change of colour?**

Comment: It also had all the words on the outside of it turned into “BAD WOLF”, so I figure Rose messed with it somewhat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the Tardis alerting the Doctor to a seriously major problem or emergency. You can hear the Cloister bells ringing.

Here's another example from Season3 Ep.13 "the Sound of Drums"
[image]

Apparently, some people think the red lighting was due to the Tardis being converted into a Paradox Machine rather than the Tardis signalling that something very bad is happening or about to happen...like someone creating a Paradox Machine.

Here's an sequential example from "Journey to the Centre of the Tardis" - a new Doctor, a new console, new control room, new blue-ish colour scheme:

**Blue-y-all-systems-go-ishness**
[image]

**Blue-y-systems-losing-power-y-ness**
[image]

**Bit-of-a-problem-redness**
[image]

**Definate-magno-grab-shields-down-vulnerable-red-alert-type-problem**
[image]

Comment: In _The Sound of Drums_, wasn't it because The Master had turned it into a Paradox machine?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - which is likely the same massage - something is terribly, horribly wrong.